# Ordering Nodes of a graph according to their degree

Tags: python, graphs

In an undirected graph, I would like to order its nodes according to their degree. However, to do this I have to enter the edges of the graph first. When I do this, **NetworkX** in Python reads the nodes from the entries of the edges and doesn't consider the contribution of the `add_nodes_from` command. Is there any way to overcome this problem? Here is a sample of code I'm using:

```
g = nx.Graph()
weighted_edges =    [(4,3,150),(1,2,15),(1,4,100),(1,3,100),(1,5,130)
                    ,(2,3,205),(2,4,211),(2,5,200),(3,5,100),(4,5,10)]
#Sorting edges according to node degree 
sorted_edges = sorted(g.degree(weight='weight'), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# extract the sorted nodes 
nodes = []
for e in range(len(sorted_edges)):
   temp = sorted_edges[e][0]
   nodes.append(temp)

g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
g.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edges)
```

according to the above sample of code, `print(nodes)` output is an **empty set**, since `add_weighted_edges_from` is coming after. When we add the edges first, `g.nodes` outputs following the order edge entries. **nodes** are meant to be the sorted nodes according to their degree, and **g.nodes** are the nodes according to the graph edges entries.
I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not a typical answer, but I decided to post this tweak to help others when they are facing the same problem.
I have added another initiation for the graph method using the same name of the graph `g=nx.graph()` just before the definition of the sorted nodes, such that the graph will consider the sorted nodes as `g.nodes`, the code will be such that

```
g = nx.Graph()
weighted_edges =    [(4,3,150),(1,2,15),(1,4,100),(1,3,100),(1,5,130)
                     ,(2,3,205),(2,4,211),(2,5,200),(3,5,100),(4,5,10)]
#Sorting edges according to node degree 
sorted_edges = sorted(g.degree(weight='weight'), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
# extract the sorted nodes 
nodes = []
for e in range(len(sorted_edges)):
    temp = sorted_edges[e][0]
    nodes.append(temp)
g=nx.graph() # this line was added to restart the graph definition
g.add_nodes_from(nodes)
g.add_weighted_edges_from(weighted_edges)
print (g.nodes)
output: NodeView((2, 3, 4, 5, 1)) # g.nodes are sorted according to the node degree
```